# The live stream won't be closed after client close browser or go to another page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

The following is my code snippet for **event stream**

However, it should print "**close a live stream**" string on the console after client close browser, but it didn't.

```
  def new_prizes_stream
    begin
      ap "open a live stream"
      response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
      redis = Redis.new
      redis.subscribe('messages.create') do |on|
        on.message do |event, data|
          response.stream.write "event: #{event}\n"
          response.stream.write "data: #{data}\n\n"
        end
      end
    rescue ActionController::Live::ClientDisconnected
    ensure
      ap "close a live stream"
      redis.quit          
      response.stream.close
    end
  end
```

#### development.rb

```
  config.allow_concurrency = true
  config.preload_frameworks = true
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.eager_load = false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis subscribe is blocking. See the issue here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10989

I use heartbeat solution in separate thread to detect the ClientDisconnected exception.